# Getting wireless card to work in Debian with wpa_supplicant

Tags: debian, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I'm having difficulty getting a Netgear WG311 network card to work with Debian. Here is a screenshot showing `ifconfig wlan0`, `iwconfig`, network interface cards, and `wpa_supplicant` configs:

I understand that the wpa doesn't work with third-party drivers and ndiswrapper; I've been told to use wpa_supplicant instead. How can I get my windows driver to work with the Netgear WG311 wireless card?

UPDATE

ok had a look at the resource that Macieg gave me. Finally got a connection but after restart it is gone.

the output of this command. wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -D wext

just shows wpa_supplicant help commands.

UPDATE2

Ok the connection comes up after restart, but only 5 minutes after i do this command

```
wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dwext
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What does output says after 5 minutes of this command (without -B)?

Comment: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
Trying to associate with 68:7f:74:47:50:96 (SSID='BigGiraffe' freq=2462 MHz)
Associated with 68:7f:74:47:50:96
WPA: Key negotiation completed with 68:7f:74:47:50:96 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 68:7f:74:47:50:96 completed (auth) [id=0 id_str=]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wpa_supplicant does have support for ndiswrapper and should be run like this:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -D wext
```

[Instructions how to install ndiswrapper drivers](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-ndiswrapper-wpa_supplicant-howto/) - however I never use ndiswrapper.

If it does not help you have to say what is the output of:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -D wext
```

---

As a side note - to use WPA you need user program called wpa supplicant. The most popular one is wpa_supplicant. Therefore the WPA stack on Linux contains of 2 elements:

- Driver. The best are mac8011 drivers (new stack on kernel). ndiswrapper is a workaround of using Windows drivers as the drivers which should work but it may happen that it does not.
- WPA Supplicant. In most cases [wpa_supplicant](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/)

Usually on top of that you want [NetworkManager](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager), [connman](http://connman.net/) or something like that.

---

PS. Preferably add text instead of screenshots as:

- They are searchable by google/bing/$SEARCH_ENGINE
- They are easier to read
- They will not disapper for whatever reason (say - maintenance break of 3rd party server)

Comment: ok. have it working, and i added the line to load the daemon at startup, but its not loading after startup. When i run this command after startup the wireless works again. I did notice that it said it want the iface to be set as manual. Also dhcpdiscover comes up a couple of times.

Comment: command. wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dwext brings up the wireless connection after startup. Internet works some times.

Comment: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS Trying to associate with 68:7f:74:47:50:96 (SSID='BigGiraffe' freq=2462 MHz) Associated with 68:7f:74:47:50:96 WPA: Key negotiation completed with 68:7f:74:47:50:96 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP] CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 68:7f:74:47:50:96 completed (auth) [id=0 id_str=]